# Override application.properties data through a rest controller end point in Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring-boot, application.properties

I want to have a RestController end point which can be used to override application.properties files.
**Requirement**:
We have one spring boot application in which we want to override few properties using Rest end point.
We tried below way but this works only if we start application, but our requirement is even if application is running we should be able to override it :

```
java -jar spring-boot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:application.properties,/opt/somewhere/override.properties
```

Is it possible? if yes then what is best way to do this?

Comment: You would still have to restart/reload your app, as these configurations might already be loaded in app environment. Now, [official documentation lists all evaluated property sources, in order of precedence](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config). You could choose an editable way (external properties file, environment variable, etc.), but you would still have to reload application context upon change.

Comment: There is also the [Spring Cloud config](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-config) project that could help you manage  external/updatable properties. However, I've never used it, so I do not know how much you can do with it.

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reloading-properties